# How do you auto update row count in a formula that yields a percentage?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

How does one get a formula to auto update when a row is added when this formula is meant to yield as a percentage, which is directly linked to a pie chart? For example: my formula reads

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B22,"=3")/20
```

with 20 being the number or rows. The formula works, but I have manually change the row count in this formula every time I add a new row. This, of course, affects my pie chart... Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your rows are B3 through B22, that you have to start counting at B3, and that there's nothing underneath them, you could use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:B100,"=3")/(COUNTA(B3:B100))
```

The function of "COUNTA" is to count every cell that is not empty. Any time a row is added underneath B22, the formula would automatically update to accommodate.